# How to connect to mysql server with entity framework core?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I started new razor project and i want to use mysql as server. i follow official example to connect mysql using entity [official example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html) and this [one](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html). i got error context builder not resolve UseMysql method. something missing here?

> error CS1061: 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseMysql'

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
using Database.Entities;

namespace Database;

public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
        => builder.UseMysql("server=localhost;database=razor;username=root;password=VuYbe*$LnjhET%IM)g7qPvZ6KQ@F#!Hr53^Bk(dGWRxXCJzaw4ft8Ns&D9pyA2m+");
}
```

file.csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.10" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.10">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.31" />
  <PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.7" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: size does matter ... (of letters)

Comment: I do not see `UseMysql` in official example  ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
```

The standard practice is to put the extension methods for Depedency Injection into Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection namespace, which is included in most ASP.NET Core app projects so the method becomes automatically available when a package is imported.

Comment: i check this package. it already deprecated. mysql suggest to use `Mysql.EntityFrameworkCore`. i add `Mysql.Data.EntityFramework` too. always error. [nuget mysql package](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/MySQL)